# Power on absolute value expressions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

How to deal with absolute value, when raised to odd number?

Like here:
$$\left|\log_2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right|^3 + |\log_2 (2x)|^3 = 28$$

Comment: Well, as you know, odd powers preserve the sign of the thing that you're raising to a power. So ... that's it. You need to keep the absolute values there and consider the different cases as usual.

Comment: Please include the associated problem in the question body. Links have a tendency to die and make for poor questions for someone coming back years from now.

Comment: @DreamConspiracy  Sorry, I'm having a problem formatting the equation . You may edit the question .

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Thanks alot. @N.F.Taussig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\log_2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)=\log_2 x-1\; \text{and} \; \log_2\left(2x\right)=\log_2 x+1.$

Set $a=\log_2x.$ The equation rewrites
$$\left|a-1\right|^3 + |a+1|^3 = 28.$$
Solve separately for $\; a<-1,\; -1\leq a \leq 1, \; a>1.$ We get $a=-2$ or $a=2.$
The solutions of the initial equation $x\in\{{1\over 4}, 4\}.$